# Bind the controls in Html table on button click

Tags: html, dom, html-table

- I a very new to programming and need your help and guidance to build
  my self.
- Below is the code written add the control in html table on button
  click event.
- But I am finding no luck in it's execution.Can any one help in
  knowing what's the issue and how can solve it

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to create a Text Field.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
 <table id="tblCustomListData" border="1" width="100%" style="overflow-x:auto;">
              <thead>
                     <tr class="bgcolorgray">
                        <th>Sno</th>
                        <th >Current DR</th>
                     </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
</div >
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


         
     
function myFunction() {

var txtHTML = "";
$('#tblCustomListData tbody').html('');

var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
x.setAttribute("type", "text");
x.setAttribute("id", "uniqueIdentifier");
x.setAttribute("value", "Hello!");
         document.body.appendChild(x);

 var row = document.createElement("tr");
 
                 txtHTML = txtHTML + "<tr>";
                  txtHTML = txtHTML + "<td>";
                     txtHTML = txtHTML +  document.getElementById("uniqueIdentifier") + "</a>";
                     txtHTML = txtHTML + "</td>";
                 txtHTML = txtHTML + "</tr>";
                 
  $("#tblCustomListData").append(txtHTML);
  
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

```
enter code here
```

Comment: For one you're using jQuery syntax (i.e. `$( ... )`) but not including jQuery. Include jQuery so `$` is not undefined like it is now. If you're going to use jQuery you might as well create elements with it and bind event handlers with it.

Comment: "But I am finding no luck in it's execution"  Please be specific. What, specifically, isn't working?   (The sample here is failing because you didn't include jQuery. Is that the issue you're trying to solve, or is it something else?)

Comment: I am unable to add the input control in html table on button click

Comment: thanks for your rapid response , I had added the update and able to see the control ,But not in Html table ,In the table I am getting error as "[object HTMLInputElement]"

Answer (score 0):

you forgot adding `.value`

to `document.getElementById("uniqueIdentifier").value`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to create a Text Field.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
 <table id="tblCustomListData" border="1" width="100%" style="overflow-x:auto;">
              <thead>
                     <tr class="bgcolorgray">
                        <th>Sno</th>
                        <th >Current DR</th>
                     </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
</div >
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


         
     
function myFunction() {

var txtHTML = "";
$('#tblCustomListData tbody').html('');

var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
x.setAttribute("type", "text");
x.setAttribute("id", "uniqueIdentifier");
x.setAttribute("value", "Hello!");
         document.body.appendChild(x);

 var row = document.createElement("tr");
 
                 txtHTML = txtHTML + "<tr>";
                  txtHTML = txtHTML + "<td>";
                     txtHTML = txtHTML +  document.getElementById("uniqueIdentifier").value + "</a>";
                     txtHTML = txtHTML + "</td>";
                 txtHTML = txtHTML + "</tr>";
                 
  $("#tblCustomListData").append(txtHTML);
  
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If we add the value it is showing the control value , But I required to show the control in the  html table row.

Comment: If we add the value it is showing the "Input" control value , But I required to show the control in the  html table rows.But where are all the text controls are showing out of the table

Comment: The tag txtHTML = txtHTML + '<input type="text"  value=""   id="'+count+'">'+"</a>"; worked fine